# Monolog Array log TypeError

Tags: php, monolog

I am successfully using Monolog in many PHP projects and I frequently use the second argument to `Monolog\\Logger` to log arrays:

```
$a = array("lemon", "banana", "apple");
$log->debug("Array: ", $a);

[2018-10-01 10:43:33] /5bb1fa556588f/62309.DEBUG: Array:  ["lemon","banana","apple"] {"file":"/path/to/file.php","line":4,"class":null,"function":"myfunc"}
```

The problem happens when $a is not an array but for some reasons it is a boolean or something else. In this situation you have more reasons to correctly log it, but when this happens Monolog throws a TypeError exception and the scripts exits after it:

```
$a = false;
$log->debug("Array: ", $a);

[2018-10-01 10:45:26] /5bb1fac59dc3e/62693.ERROR: Uncaught Exception TypeError: "Argument 2 passed to Monolog\Logger::debug() must be of the type array, boolean given, called in /path/to/file.php on line 4" at /path/to/project/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php line 530 {"exception":"[object] (TypeError(code: 0): Argument 2 passed to Monolog\\Logger::debug() must be of the type array, boolean given, called in /path/to/file.php on line 4 at /path/to/project/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php:530)"} {"file":null,"line":null,"class":null,"function":null}
```

This is because Monolog does not automatically cast the given variable to array.

I am not thinking this is wrong, but I wish to understand what is the better way to solve this problem:

- cast the second argument to array: `$log->debug("Array: ", (array)$a);`
- write a custom function which wraps the call to Monolog and cast the second argument to array
- catch the TypeError exception and skip that log
- any other idea?

Comment: Better - do not cast the value, but wrap it with your own array, like:

$log->debug("Array: ", ['context' => $a]);

Comment: Thanks Sergej for the advice. Could you explain me why this is better than casting the value to array?

Comment: Because, otherwise you will not know the actual value of variable $a on the debug moment. If it is not an array - make a serialization ot something similar.

Comment: Can you write me an example, please? I know that if you cast anything to array this would give an array with one single key with the given variable, and the variable type is preserved in the value of the key.

Comment: $log->debug("Array: ", is_array($a) ? $a : ['not_array_context' => serialize($a)]);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Monolog is a common PHP logging library which implements the [PSR-3](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-3/) LoggerInterface. If you take a look at that definition of how the `debug()` method should behave you will see that [the second argument (`$context`) must be an array](https://github.com/php-fig/log/blob/master/Psr/Log/LoggerInterface.php#L111). This is why you're getting a type error. It's not possible for Monolog to let you pass a non-array type to this method since it's dictated by the interface.

```
public function debug($message, array $context = array());
```

I think out of the options that you've suggested so far, the best is to cast your context var as an array (like in your example).

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was to edit the Monolog vendor plugin itself, (`/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php`)

The functions implementing the Logger Interface ( `emergency(...)`, `alert(...)`, `log(...)`, etc...) all were using a signature like
`emergency( Stringable|string $message, array $context )`.
However, the Logger Interface expects the `$message` parameter to be typeless.

**TL;DR:** Running a quick find-and-replace to replace "Stringable|string $message" with "$message" in the file